# _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "" (when my variable gets empty)

Tags: string, tkinter, floating-point

this is my first time asking for help. I am not really an expert, so I hope this is not a newby question (sorry if it is).
Anyway, in a program in which I try to do a simple task (trying to get the lenght of a variable) with this expression:

```
if len(str(Precio.get()))>10:
```

I get this error:

_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

As you have already deducted, I´m using Tkinter. Precio is DoubleVar() type.
This error seems to arrive whenever the variable gets empty.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `StringVar` instead of `DoubleVar` and convert it to float explicitly when the content is not empty.

Comment: Thanks acw1668, I will have to do it that way. I supposed there was another way, but seems it doesn´t.